# Score up when picture not null - elasticsearch-1.7

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field picture and I implement a search of users.
The goal is to show first the people with picture, then the people without it.

I am maintaining an Elasticsearch 1.7 project and I can't upgrade the version.

The mapping:

```
"user": {
    "_all": {
      "auto_boost": true
    },
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "string",
        "store": true
      },
      "picture": {
        "type": "string",
        "store": true
      }
```

It seems that the query Exist / Missing Query does not exist in [ElasticSearch 1.7 (doc)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-queries.html)

When user doens not have picture, it is stored as `null`. When he has one, it is store with the filename: `xxx.jpg` or `yyyy.PNG`

I tried to do a query like that:

```
{
  "track_scores": true,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "filtered": {
            "filter": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "user.enabled": true
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "picture": {
              "query": ".jpg .png .JPG .PNG",
              "operator": "or"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried also :

```
/* ...  */
"should": [
    {
      "terms": {
        "minimum_match": 1,
        "teacher.picture": [
          ".jpg",
          ".png",
          ".JPG",
          ".PNG"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

I still have results with picture mixed with the one with no pictures...

Do you know how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mentioned your goal is to just show first the people with the pic and then the people without the pic. So you can simply just use _missing in sort.

With your following changes you would not be able to get people who don't have a picture, so don't chase exists query.

```
/* ...  */
"should": [
    {
      "terms": {
        "minimum_match": 1,
        "teacher.picture": [
          ".jpg",
          ".png",
          ".JPG",
          ".PNG"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

[Instead use _missing in score.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-request-sort.html#_missing_values)

```
{
  "track_scores": true,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "filtered": {
            "filter": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "user.enabled": true
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "picture": {
              "query": ".jpg .png .JPG .PNG",
              "operator": "or"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
   "sort" : [
        { "picture" : {"missing" : "_last"} },
    ]
}
```

Hope this helps.
Thanks

Comment: FYI, I additionnaly removed the `should match picture` section. Thanks a lot it works like a charm

Comment: yes, i kept them as i was not aware of your purpose to do a should as you wanted people without profile pic as well. i am glad this worked for you. Thanks